# Extra generic parameter for AutoMapper

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

Besides source and destination types, how to add another type parameter to mapping which will be used to call a method with generic parameter while performing the mapping?

Comment: There's no way to add a parameter directly but you've got a few options off the top of my head.  You can write your own ITypeConverter, or you could create a custom attribute and use reflection to read the attribute value in your mapping.

Comment: It seems ITypeConverter is less obtrusive but how to pass third Type with ITypeConverter implementation.

Comment: You can pass parameters to the type converter's constructor.  If you're not using dependency injection, you would register the converter like mapper.CreateMap<A, B>().ConvertUsing(new CustomTypeConverter("myargument");